# MonoTouch Activation Fails

Tags: iphone, macos, xamarin.ios, osx-snow-leopard

I'm having issues activating MonoTouch on my system. I get the following error:

[image: Error message]

I've got the latest Mono and MonoDevelop. I'm running on Snow Leopard.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest http://support.xamarin.com/ to get some proper answers or the mailing list at monotouch.net

Comment: @lngenu That site suggest stackoverflow, which would suggest they offer support here. Thanks though!

Comment: I think they meant it for help with programming issues. irc.gnome.org #monotouch is also a place where Miguel and others hang out. However, from the activity I've seen, the mailing list is better at getting great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) offers MonoTouch support here on stackoverflow, on [IRC](http://ios.xamarin.com/Chat?highlight=irc) (e.g. #monotouch on GIMPNet), on it's [mailing-lists](http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/monotouch), it's [support site](http://support.xamarin.com/)... our users are everywhere and we're happy to help wherever they are and see them help out each others :-)

However for activation related issue you should use the "[customer self-service](http://activation.monotouch.net/)" or the [private email form](http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/emails/new) since you might need to disclose personal information.

[disclosure: I work for Xamarin]